# Visio: Way to force arrowhead at intersection with shape?

Tags: visio

Is there a way to force Visio to draw an arrowhead at the point where a line intersects a connected shape?

I.e. custom connection points are super inconvenient as they never seem to be where you need them, especially if you are still moving shapes around trying to get the right arrangement. Instead I would like to connect shapes using a line attached to each shape's center point and have Visio draw the arrowheads where the line intersects the connected shape.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Visio are you using?

What you describe is the standard behaviour for Visio. Visio connects to the connection points around the edge. The connection will highligt in red to indicate where it connects. If the entire shape highligts red then the connection point will be the nearest point in the direction ofthe other shape. So rather than connect to a fixed point, the point will move depending where the other shape is.

Comment: @john-visio-mvp  Thank you, I am using Visio 2007. Does the shape need to support this behavior or is it an intrinsic behavior?  I am using standard block diagram shapes and I don't seem to be able to cause the entire shape to hilight as a connection point.

Comment: Lol, OK so you have to use the Connector Tool and not the line tool. There is a good post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visio/archive/2006/09/15/better-layout-using-dynamic-glue.aspx).